# CSV export from database in zend framework2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have csv icon on the above of the listing and when i click on csv icon i need that records as csv.i follow this link:http://www.masterzendframework.com/tutorial/simple-csv-output-in-zend-framework-2 but not helpful for me.

Comment: We will need to see the relevant part of your code, and what errors you're getting in order to be able to help you. Please edit your question to include this info.

Comment: You could try using a module to export csv files - http://modules.zendframework.com/?query=csv

Answer (score 0):

It's not absolutely necessary to go with a view.
You can simply build the csv and echo it on the go.

Example in a controller or related service:

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . date('Y-m-d_H-i') . '.csv"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";  // BOM header UTF-8

$fh = @fopen('php://output', 'w');

$header = [];

foreach ($columns as $column) {
    $header[] = $column['name'];
}

// Write header
fputcsv($fh, $header, ';');

foreach ($data as $value) {
    fputcsv($fh, $value, ';');
}

fclose($fh);
```